# APIs finding lat-long

Tags: iphone, timezone

I am going to create an app just like World clock for iphone.
I actually want to knw that is there any API or function which 
returns timezone or lat-long on providing
city name.
  If anybody knws, plz reply me.

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632100/figure-out-time-by-latitude-longitude

Comment: Ok...I will take a look through it.

Answer (score 0):

[Programmable Web](http://www.programmableweb.com/apis) is a useful resource for searching for APIs, here's one that looks promising: [TimeZoneDB](http://www.programmableweb.com/api/timezonedb).

Comment: What you mean like repeat and paraphrase other people on a system which is setup and designed to utilise hyperlinks so information can be joined up? Yeah i like the idea of cutting and pasting large chuncks of hyperlinked text into web apps. I will get right on to it for you.

Comment: No need to be snarky, just add a little more context, so people understand what they're clicking on, and might be able to search for it should the link break.