# get Time Zone using latitude and longitude?

Tags: php, iphone

I having current latitude and longitude and I want the Time Zone from that latitude and longitude. (I want that this latitude and longitude from which Time Zone)

I want output like.

```
Latitude:22.5726460
Longitude:88.3638950
```

This is latitude longitude of Kolkata,india and when I have this lat long I want Asia/Kolkata(as Output)

Please suggest any api or any idea which can solve out my problem

Answer (score 3):

you can calculate the time zone yourself for more help refer this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4633247/919545) may be this can help you....

**EDIT:**
you can use the weatherbug api to get the exact time using your lat/long

Comment: It's good but I want that when I have not selected any timezone in my app I want to selecte time zone from the current latitude and longitude so I want it.

Comment: you can use the weatherbug api to get the exact time using your lat/long

Answer (score 2):

I just came around with similar project recently. I now using the web service provided by [GeoNames](http://www.geonames.org/export/ws-overview.html) and [TimeZoneDB](http://timezonedb.com/api).

Both service need to register a API key.

GeoNames:
    api.geonames.org/findNearbyPlaceName?lat=47.3&lng=9&username=demo&style=full

TimeZoneDB:
    api.timezonedb.com/?lat=53.7833&lng=-1.75&key=KEY

Answer (score 1):

Your question may same like

[Web service - current time zone for a city?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55901/web-service-current-time-zone-for-a-city)

You can use webservice, http://www.earthtools.org/webservices.htm#timezone ,

example :

http://www.earthtools.org/timezone-1.1/40.71417/-74.00639