# How to get timezone by latitude and longitude

Tags: ios, geolocation, timezone

I need to display  date and time based on the given lat/long in the app. I worked with Google API to get the timezone ID, but it should work offline too. Is there any way to get timezone without being connected to the internet?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632100/figure-out-time-by-latitude-longitude/4633247#4633247 this is relevant.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16086962/how-to-get-a-time-zone-from-a-location-using-latitude-and-longitude-coordinates this is also relevant..

Comment: Ridiculous, this is not a duplicate of that question. It's specifically about iOS and this question comes up first on Google and have no good answers for 2019 (Swift, modern iOS versions). The linked question doesn't have solutions for iOS.

Answer (score 3):

Try this one :

```
CLLocation *location = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:50.449846
                                                  longitude:30.523629];

NSTimeZone *timeZone = [[APTimeZones sharedInstance] timeZoneWithLocation:location];
NSLog(@"%@", timeZone);
```

Find Library Here : https://github.com/Alterplay/APTimeZones

---

You can also do it by code (answered by https://stackoverflow.com/a/27054583/3202193):

```
CLLocation *currentLocaiton = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude];

[geoCoder reverseGeocodeLocation:currentLocaiton completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {

    if (error == nil && [placemarks count] > 0) {

        placeMark = [placemarks lastObject];
         NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"identifier = \"[a-z]*\\/[a-z]*_*[a-z]*\"" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:NULL];
        NSTextCheckingResult *newSearchString = [regex firstMatchInString:[placeMark description] options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [placeMark.description length])];
        NSString *substr = [placeMark.description substringWithRange:newSearchString.range];
        NSLog(@"timezone id %@",substr); 

    }
```

Comment: +1 for the APTimeZones lib, it has offline database of timezones and work with it. But may be inaccurate in some cases, look at Issues tab of the project. Problems may arise with daylight saving timezone change, and another cases

Comment: APTimeZones does a nearest-point lookup, which is often going to be wrong.  See their [issue #2](https://github.com/Alterplay/APTimeZones/issues/2) and the part of [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16086964/634824) with the diagram of the two squares.